# Use virtual machine to create preconfigured OS

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, iso-image

So I was thinking can I download Ubuntu ISO file and boot it into a virtual machine like Vmware or Virtualbox and then I downloaded/edit/update all the necessary files then make a new ISO file to boot it into another PC and have all the changes I made, is it possible? if so can someone guide me to a tutorial as I don't know the technical terms to search for

Comment: You will need to extract the ISO, make edits directly to the extracted content, and create a new bootable ISO.  You are doing it the hard way.  There are many tools to help you make the live iso whatever you want it to be.  Google [creating a linux live ISO](https://www.google.com/search?&q=creating+a+linux+live+ISO&oq=creating+a+linux+live+ISO&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB46BwgAEEcQsAM6CAghEBYQHRAeUNUuWL4yYPc0aAJwAHgAgAFciAHuAZIBATOYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjlhIy6svDqAhVLPn0KHWxZBuEQ4dUDCAw&uact=5)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas but live OS reset after rebooting it does keep changes

Comment: That is my point.  You are not going to boot a live ISO, edit it, and save the changes.  Live boots are only in memory.